# Change a tuple within a list of tuples

Tags: python, string, list, tuples, similarity

I am reading in data from multiple Excel files and writing them back to an aggregated Excel file.

So I have this output, and it represents the relations of multiple entities within my company (`enity-ID`) with other companies (`debitor-name`):

```py
debitor_list = [
    ("1", "X AG"),
    ("1", "X AG"),
    ("1", "Z AG"),
    ("2", "X AG"),
    ("2", "X AG"),
    ("3", "LOL AG"),
    ("1", "Z AG"), 
    ("1", "HS AG"),
    ("2", "hs ag")
]
```

The tuples structure within this list is the following:

```py
('entity-ID', 'debitor-name')
```

In addition, I have a list which represents the *real* names and information about debitors:

```py
real_file = ["LOLLIPOP AG", "HS AG", "X AG", "Z AG"]
```

Then I am checking for similarities between debitor name in `debitor_list` and `real_file` to replace with the *real* name:

```py
import difflib as dif

for deb in debitor_list:
    for cam in cam_file:
        if deb[1] != cam:
            sequence = dif.SequenceMatcher(
                isjunk=None,
                a=deb[1].lower(),
                b=cam.lower()
            )
            match = sequence.ratio() * 100
            if (match >= 80):
                print(deb[1], cam, match)
                debitor_list.append((deb[0], cam))
```

Output:

```
hs ag HS AG 100.0
```

How can I delete the `("2", "hs ag")` tuple?

Comment: Convert the `tuples` into `lists`, then replace the old string with the best match?

Comment: create a new list and append new tuples to it. use this new list to create the aggregated excel file

Comment: So I got the appending part working but is there no easy way for deleting the wrong written entry?

Comment: what are the imports that are needed to run this code?

Comment: import difflib as dif

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do here. Why do you have the same names with two different `entity-id`? What is the expected output of your code?

Comment: So the entity-id gives me the entity within my company and multiple entities can have a relationship to one certain debitor. I hope that explains it.

Comment: I am creating this output so far: [(['2', '1'], 'X AG'),
 (['1'], 'Z AG'),
 (['3'], 'LOL AG'),
 (['1'], 'HS AG'),
 (['2'], 'hs ag')]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you replace the whole list, or you replace the element in place with some simple logic, see the 2 options below.

Note that tuples might be immutable, but the list itself is not...

```py
import difflib as dif

debitor_list = [
    ("1", "X AG"),
    ("1", "X AG"),
    ("1", "Z AG"),
    ("2", "X AG"),
    ("2", "X AG"),
    ("3", "LOL AG"),
    ("1", "Z AG"),
    ("1", "HS AG"),
    ("2", "hs ag"),
]

real_file = ["LOLLIPOP AG", "HS AG", "X AG", "Z AG"]


def fix_stuff(d_list, c_list):
    result = []
    for deb in d_list:
        repl_val = None
        for cam in c_list:
            if deb[1] != cam:
                sequence = dif.SequenceMatcher(
                    isjunk=None, a=deb[1].lower(), b=cam.lower()
                )
                match = sequence.ratio() * 100
                if match >= 80:
                    repl_val = cam
        if repl_val:
            result.append((deb[0], repl_val))
        else:
            result.append(deb)
    return result


print(debitor_list)
new_deb_list = fix_stuff(debitor_list, real_file)
print(new_deb_list)


for idx, deb in enumerate(debitor_list):
    for cam in real_file:
        if deb[1] != cam:
            sequence = dif.SequenceMatcher(isjunk=None, a=deb[1].lower(), b=cam.lower())
            match = sequence.ratio() * 100
            if match >= 80:
                debitor_list[idx] = (deb[0], cam)
print(debitor_list)
```

**output**

```py
[('1', 'X AG'), ('1', 'X AG'), ('1', 'Z AG'), ('2', 'X AG'), ('2', 'X AG'), ('3', 'LOL AG'), ('1', 'Z AG'), ('1', 'HS AG'), ('2', 'hs ag')]
[('1', 'X AG'), ('1', 'X AG'), ('1', 'Z AG'), ('2', 'X AG'), ('2', 'X AG'), ('3', 'LOL AG'), ('1', 'Z AG'), ('1', 'HS AG'), ('2', 'HS AG')]
[('1', 'X AG'), ('1', 'X AG'), ('1', 'Z AG'), ('2', 'X AG'), ('2', 'X AG'), ('3', 'LOL AG'), ('1', 'Z AG'), ('1', 'HS AG'), ('2', 'HS AG')]
```

---

The `if repl_val` checks if the value needs to be replaced. Since the variable `repl_val` gets set to `None` at the start of each for, `if repl_val` will only be true if it was changed during the loop.

As for using `result`, when using the function, we're not modifying the incoming lists, but we return a new list `result`.

---

as for the second way to do this (and that is likely the better way), due to the usage of `enumerate` we get an index (`idx`) for each list element, as well as the value `deb`. It allows for directly assigning to the original list by it's index, so it's a direct modification of the original list.

Comment: thank you sir! But tbh I dont get what you are doing in the last part / last for loop.

Comment: And for what purpose do you create the result = [] list?

Comment: see my updated answer with some explanation at the bottom. I advise you to use the second method as it's a nicer and easier-to-read method of doing this...